# Replace() not working

Tags: python, methods, replace

it's been more than 20 minutes I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with something so simple, the `World` doesn't change to `There` uing this code:

```
test = "Hello World"
print test
test.replace("World", "There")
print test
```

I know words can be replaced using other methods, I just wanna know what am I doing wrong here. :(

Comment: Oh, I couldn't find something similar. thanks

Comment: Split first `test.split(" ")` then `test.replace("World", "There")`